# Не работает setSelection(), smoothScrollToPosition() и прочее, как быть?

Tags: android, listview

Есть у меня ListView, заполняемый SimpleCursorAdapter из БД. Я хочу его промотать до определенной позиции, но ни один из методов не работает вообще никак. В чем проблема?

Comment: Давайте посмотрим на код, иначе не получится понять.

Comment: У Вас не работает сама подгрузка с БД или данные успешно подгружаються, а не работают определенные методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, выполнял все onCreate, и получилось решить проблему, запустив все в новом View.post Runnable.

```
my_lv.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    my_lv.requestFocusFromTouch();
    my_lv.setSelection(posit);   
}
});
```